# Sorting n strings of size n?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I want to sort  n strings each of length n in `O(n^2)` ? Is their any other solution beside radix based sorting or trie based ?

Comment: Why doesn't trie or radix sort fit your problem? It is unlikely that there is anything simpler than that.

Comment: Because there is no fixed number of alphabets from which strings are constructed.

Comment: MAybe you can explain a bit more. Whatever you have can be represented as groups of *n* symbols, and the symbols at the same position in different groups can be compared with each other. Are you looking for an in-place algorithm? Quicksort?

Comment: if you do not have 'finite' or low enough alphabet count then you can not solve this in O(n^2) by standard programing means. the best you can do is O((n^2)*log(n)). When standard means are not enough usually neural network kicks in but creation of correct sorting by neural network approach can be nasty

Comment: also you want the best complexity or runtime? because they are very different things ... for that you should add target platform, resources and data specification like used n-range, alphabet, and statistical properties of string dataset...

Comment: I am interested in worst case complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you try using a comparison-based sort. Comparing two strings of length n takes, in the worst case, time O(n). Consequently, in the worst case, you'd have to make only O(n) comparisons to sort the strings. However, that's impossible, since comparison-based sorting algorithms require Ω(n log n) comparisons on average. This worst-case can be realized; starting with the array x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>, you can form the strings a<sup>n-1</sup>x<sub>1</sub>, a<sup>n-1</sup>x<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sup>n-1</sup>x<sub>n</sub>, and comparisons will take time Θ(n) each.

That rules out comparison sorts, which leaves behind approaches that harness actual properties of strings. The approaches you listed - trie-based approaches and radix sort - form the basis for most of the algorithms along these lines (in fact, to the best of my knowledge, all string sorting algorithms are variations on these themes). There are nicely-optimized implementations of these algorithms. For example, [burstsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burstsort) is an optimized radix sort that's designed to be cache-friendly, and therefore has better performance than the naive algorithm.

One detail that you need to keep in mind is that the size of the alphabet from which your strings are drawn does have an impact on the runtime. Radix sort on strings of length n more properly takes time O(n<sup>2</sup> + n|Σ|), where |Σ| is the number of different characters that the strings can be made from. Consequently, you can't necessarily use radix sort to sort n strings of length n in time O(n<sup>2</sup>) if there are way more than n characters in your alphabet.